# How could I prevent the addition of the space between the `if` and the opening parentheses in C# FixFormat in VS Code extension?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, indentation

How could I prevent the addition of the space between the `if` and the opening parentheses in C# FixFormat in VS Code extension?

I researched the settings for the plugin inside the VS Code. Also, I read [the documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Leopotam.csharpfixformat). It seems that there is no way to do that. And here I am asking in hope that maybe someone was able to figure out how to overcome this.

E.g. the plugin formats my code like that:

`if (myBooleanCheck)`

while I would like it to be formatted like that:

`if(myBooleanCheck)`.